# How to get Wikipedia page HTML with absolute URLs using the API?

Tags: php, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to retrieve articles through wikipedia API using this code

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=example&format=json&prop=text';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$c = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($c);
$content = $json->{'parse'}->{'text'}->{'*'};
```

I can view the content in my website and everything is fine but I have a problem with the links inside the article that I have retrieved. If you open the url you can see that all the links start with href=\"/
meaning that if someone clicks on any related link in the article it redirects him to **www.mysite.com**/wiki/.. (Error 404) instead of **en.wikipedia.com**/wiki/..
Is there any piece of code that I can add to the existing one to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a shortcoming in the MediaWiki `action=parse` API.  In fact, someone already filed [a feature request asking for an option to make `action=parse` return full URLs](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40128).

As a workaround, you could either try to mangle the links yourself (like adil suggests), or use `index.php?action=render` like this:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=render&title=Example

This will *only* give you the page HTML with no API wrapper, but if that's all you want anyway then it should be fine.  (For example, this is the method used internally by [InstantCommons](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/InstantCommons) to show remote file description pages.)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to fix the links like this:

```
$content = str_replace('<a href="/w', '<a href="//en.wikipedia.org/w', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needs to replace all instances of the URL.

You'll need to use regex and the `g` flag

`/<a href="\/w/g`